# How would I able get my code to not output the scores of invalid and DQed athletes?

Tags: c++

C++ Question: I was wondering what I could do to not have my code print out the scores for the invalid and disqualified athletes. I just want it to only print the error message. What changes would I need to make?

Here is what goes in the .txt file for the input file:

```
Mirabella Jones
7.5 8.8 7.0 8.1 8.0 9.8 9.3 8.9 9.1 9.0
Ruth Mendez
9.8 8.5 6.0 8.8 8.6 7.1 7.8 8.0 7.2 8.3
Melvin Ingram
9.9 7.3 6.3 7.0 6.8 -0.1 8.9 9.5 6.5 6.0
Tara Silva
8.1 7.1 9.4 7.2 9.2 6.4 9.5 8.4 6.7 6.6
Joann Gardner
6.9 8.0 8.7 8.9 9.1 7.5 8.2 6.3 8.4 10.1
Jeff Barnes
6.4 7.2 8.3 8.6 7.9 6.0 7.1 6.7 9.5 9.9
```

Output:

```
Mirabella Jones's results:
7.5, 8.8, 7, 8.1, 8, 9.8, 9.3, 8.9, 9.1, 9
The highest score of 9.8 and the lowest score of 7 were dropped
The average score is 8.59

Ruth Mendez's results:
9.8, 8.5, 6, 8.8, 8.6, 7.1, 7.8, 8, 7.2, 8.3
The highest score of 9.8 and the lowest score of 6 were dropped
The average score is 8.04

Invalid scores. Melvin Ingram is disqualified

Melvin Ingram's results:
9.9, 7.3, 6.3, 7, 6.8, -0.1
The highest score of 9.9 and the lowest score of -0.1 were dropped
The average score is 3.42

Tara Silva's results:
8.1, 7.1, 9.4, 7.2, 9.2, 6.4, 9.5, 8.4, 6.7, 6.6
The highest score of 9.5 and the lowest score of 6.4 were dropped
The average score is 7.84

Invalid scores. Joann Gardner is disqualified

Joann Gardner's results:
6.9, 8, 8.7, 8.9, 9.1, 7.5, 8.2, 6.3, 8.4, 10.1
The highest score of 10.1 and the lowest score of 6.3 were dropped
The average score is 8.21

Jeff Barnes's results:
6.4, 7.2, 8.3, 8.6, 7.9, 6, 7.1, 6.7, 9.5, 9.9
The highest score of 9.9 and the lowest score of 6 were dropped
The average score is 7.71
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    //constant 
    constexpr unsigned MIN_SCORE {}; //const for min score
    constexpr unsigned MAX_SCORE {10}; //const for MAX_SCORE
    constexpr size_t NUM_OF_SCORES {10}; //const for NUM_OF_SCORES
    const std::string SCORES_FILENAME = "scorecard2.txt"; //pull text file

    // open the file with the test scores and check if successful
    std::ifstream scoreFile(SCORES_FILENAME);
    //file could not be opened
    if (!scoreFile)
        return (std::cout << "ERROR: the score file could not be opened\n"), 1;
    for (std::string athletes_name, line; std::getline(scoreFile, athletes_name) && std::getline(scoreFile, line);) {
        double lowest_score {11.0};     // variable to store lowest score
        double highest_score {};        // variable to store highest score
        double total_score {};          // variable to store total score
        double scores[NUM_OF_SCORES] {};    // array to read the scores into
        std::istringstream ilscores(line); //for output
        size_t no_score {}; //to hold no score
        bool disqual {}; //true or false for disqualification
    //invalid scores
        for (; !disqual && no_score < NUM_OF_SCORES && ilscores >> scores[no_score]; ++no_score) {
            if (scores[no_score] < MIN_SCORE || scores[no_score] > MAX_SCORE) {
                std::cout << "\nInvalid scores. " << athletes_name << " is disqualified\n";
                disqual = true;
            }

            total_score += scores[no_score];
            //when calculating no scores for lowest and highest
            if (scores[no_score] < lowest_score)
                lowest_score = scores[no_score];

            if (scores[no_score] > highest_score)
                highest_score = scores[no_score];
        }
    //insufficent scores
        if (!disqual && no_score != NUM_OF_SCORES)
            std::cout << "\nInsufficient scores. \n" << athletes_name << " is disqualified\n";
        else {
            std::cout << '\n' << athletes_name << "\'s results:\n";
            //scores output
            for (size_t s = 0; s < no_score; ++s)
                std::cout << scores[s] << (s == no_score - 1 ? "\n" : ", ");

            total_score -= highest_score + lowest_score; // exclude highest and lowest score
            const auto average_score {total_score / 8.0};  // average calculation
            //output
            std::cout << "The highest score of " << std::setprecision(3) << highest_score << " and the lowest score of " << std::setprecision(3) << lowest_score << " were dropped\n";
            std::cout << "The average score is " << std::setprecision(3) << average_score << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `if (!disqual)` around the bit that prints the scores?

Comment: You wrote this whole program and managed to print when one was disqualified, but you can't skip output altogether then? Check different flow control features like `break`, `return`, `continue`, `if` and `else`, they should give you the tools to achieve this. That said, it might be easiest if you created a textual description of what you want to do in human language first.